# MATLAB: Define a new matrix as a linear combination of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example:

```
B1 = 1*A1 + 2*A2;
B2 = 3*A1 + 4*A2;
```

B1, B2, A1, A2 are all 2 by 2 matrices.

How can I define the B's matrices efficiently? by doing something like:

```
[B1;B2] = [1 2;3 4]*[A1;A2]
```

It fails. I want to doing such things because my task is not just to define two matrices so I can type it by hand.

Comment: @Stewie Griffin `1 2;3 4` is just extracted from the coefficient. But I guess it can be stored as a variable for compactness. Yes they can be two "layers" in the third dimension. But I need to get back B1 and B2 at the end.

Comment: So, did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use an approach similar to [**TroyHaskin**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691536/3372061)'s, but using [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
A1 = 1i*ones(2); % Using imaginary numbers so the result is easier to verify visually.
A2 = magic(2);   % [1,3; 4,2]
C = [1 2; 3 4];

B = sum(cat(3,kron(C(:,1),A1),kron(C(:,2),A2)),3);

B =

   2.0000 + 1.0000i   6.0000 + 1.0000i
   8.0000 + 1.0000i   4.0000 + 1.0000i
   4.0000 + 3.0000i  12.0000 + 3.0000i
  16.0000 + 3.0000i   8.0000 + 3.0000i
```

The resulting `B` array contains `B1` and `B2` "stacked vertically" (i.e. along the 1<sup>st</sup> dimension) such that `B1 = B(1:2,:); B2 = B(3:4,:);`.

This can be reshaped, as [**Divakar**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689457/matlab-define-a-new-matrix-as-a-linear-combination-of-matrices/38693650?noredirect=1#comment64766965_38693650) suggested, into a 3d array using:

```
B_3D = permute(reshape(B,2,2,[]),[1,3,2]);
% ... or straight away using:
B_3D = permute(reshape(sum(cat(3,kron(C(:,1),A1),kron(C(:,2),A2)),3),2,2,[]),[1,3,2]);
```

If you find working with cells easier, `B` can be converted to an `Nx1` cell array of `2x2` matrices using:

```
B_C = mat2cell(B,2*ones(size(B,1)/2,1),2);
```

Verification:

```
isequal(B_C{1}, 1*A1 + 2*A2)

ans =

     1

isequal(B_C{2}, 3*A1 + 4*A2)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: Or if OP wants a 3D array of stacked `B's`, maybe : `permute(reshape(out,2,2,[]),[1,3,2])`, where out is that `sum(cat(3,...)`.

Comment: I thought there might be a way with `kron`, but I posted my first instinctual answer. Nicely done.

Answer (score 7):

**An implementation using `matrix-multiplication`**

Let's assume there's a `2D` array `scale` that stores the scaling parameters. So, for our case, we would have -

```
scale = [1 2;3 4];
```

To start off, let stack up the `A-matrices` as a 3D array -

```
A = cat(3,A1,A2); % Add more matrices here
```

Finally, the computation itself could be implemented as a matrix-multiplication after reshaping to a `2D` and one more reshaping after the matrix-multiplication to get those `B-matrices` stacked as a 3D array -

```
B = reshape(reshape(A,4,[])*scale.',2,2,[])
```

Answer (score 3):

A rather straight-forward solution that occurs to me is to perform a scalar multiplication along the third dimension and then `sum` it away for each couple of combination coefficients to produce a cell array `B`.  The cell array arises from the output requirements of `cellfun`.

```
>> A1 = ones(2);
>> A2 = 2*A1;
>> A3 = cat(3,A1,A2);
>> B  = cellfun(@(a) sum(bsxfun(@times,A3,cat(3,a(1),a(2))),3),{[1,2],[3,4]},'UniformOutput',false);
>> B{1} == 1*A1 + 2*A2
ans =
     1     1
     1     1
>> B{2} == 3*A1 + 4*A2
ans =
     1     1
     1     1
```

Answer (score -1):

using varargin , varargout , repmat , repelem , diag... to make a 3 dimensional array (result) and calculate sum along third dimension:

```
function varargout = linear_comb(coef,varargin)
if exist('repelem') == 0 % octave friendly
    repelem = @(a,n) repelems(a,[1:numel(a);repmat(n,1,numel(a))]);
end
matdim = size(varargin{1},1);
Nvar = length(varargin);
Ncoef = size(coef, 1);
result = reshape( repmat(cell2mat(varargin),1,Ncoef) * diag(repelem(reshape(coef',1,numel(coef)),matdim)), [matdim,matdim, Nvar*Ncoef]);
    for i = 1:Ncoef
       varargout{i} = sum(result(:,:,Nvar*(i-1) +1:Nvar*i),3);
    end
end
%%example
coef=[1 2 3;3 4 1;5 6 9;7 8 4];
a1=[1 2;3 4];a2=[5 6; 7 8];a3=[9 10;11 12];
[b1 b2 b3 b4]=linear_comb(coef,a1,a2,a3)
```

Edit: more explanation

mulitiplication of a scalar by a matrix is the same as mulitiplication of a diagonal matrix with its diagonal elements equal to the scalar by the matrix.
so in our example with 2*2 matrix:

a * A === diag([a a]) * A;

a * A === diag(repelem(a,size(A,1))) * A;

all other thing is reshape and repmat to adjust and expand the size of matrix for multiplication.
varargin and varargout used to handle variable length input and output so we can write

```
[b1 b2 b3 ..bn] = linear_comb(coef, a1, a2 ,...am);
```

Comment: Some explanation on how your code works would be nice. There are a lot of advanced features here that not many novices will understand.

Comment: @rayryeng I believe that advanced features, if any, should lead to simpler an more expressive and efficient code. I upvoted Divakar's answer because it is simple, efficient and expressive. However some explanations added.

Comment: I agree but your code doesn't exhibit what you say. To each their own I suppose. Good luck!

Comment: A question before answered is difficult when answered becomes simple

Answer (score -2):

If you are familiar with C programming, it is rather easy to create a mex function to do this. Since this is a separable operation, you can also very easily use openMP to parallelize this.

Something along these lines:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
             int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

  plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(4,2,mxREAL);
  double* c_matrix = (double*) mxGetPr(prhs[0]);


  double* a1 = (double*) mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
  double* a2 = (double*) mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
  double* out = (double*) mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

  double alpha_1 = c_matrix[0];
  double alpha_2 = c_matrix[2];
  double alpha_3 = c_matrix[1];
  double alpha_4 = c_matrix[3];

  for (int i = 0;i<2;i++)
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            out[i+j*4] = alpha_1*a1[i+j*2]+alpha_2*a2[i+j*2];
            out[2+i+j*4] = alpha_3*a1[i+j*2]+alpha_4*a2[i+j*2];
        }
}
```

All the dimensions are hard coded and no checks are made, but this may be what you need. Just use mex to compile it.
The inner for-loop can be parallelized using openMP, use the pragma if you are familiar with it. But this does not seem worthwhile for such small matrices.

Comment: Retracted my downvote since you updated this with actual code that (I guess) works. I believe this is a bit overkill though (and not necessarily fast) for this task though. 2-by-2 isn't really big. :)

Comment: Using MEX is overkill for small matrices.